# Why does this NSMutableArray lose a member when it initializes an NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, ios

There must be something I don't understand about dictionaries.  I have the following code:

```
NSArray *keys=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"first person singular", @"second person singular", @"third person singular", @"first person plural", @"second person plural", @"third person singular", nil];
//This array logs a count of 6.

NSMutableArray *endingsPossible = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"iar", @"iēris", @"iētur", @"iēmur", @"iēminī", @"ientur", nil];  
//This array logs a count of 6.

NSDictionary *setOfEndings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:endingsPossible forKeys:keys];  
//This dictionary logs a count of 5.
```

How is one of the members getting lost?

Comment: If you print the contents of both what do you get?

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted or closed.  Perfectly legit question with a very concrete answer.  And, yes, this anti-pattern does lead to real world bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"third person singular" key is repeated twice.

Comment: HA!  I'll accept this as soon as I can....  File under "d'oh!".

Comment: It's not repeated twice, it's repeated once.

Answer (score 2):

You have duplicate entries for your keys, `third person singular`. That is why you only get 5 objects. Change it to `third person plural` for expected output I guess.

Comment: Absolutely right!  Just goes to show you...sometimes it's even more obvious than you think!